# ZyXEL WRE2205v2 Bricked?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, repeater, wireless-extender

I have a ZyXEL WRE2205 v2 Wifi Repeater. I followed the steps from
[this link](http://www.tgreer.com/simple-guide-use-as-an-access-point-switching-from-zyxel-wre2205-on-edimax-ew-7438apn-for-wlan-from-lan-cable.html) to transform it into an Access Point. I think the steps only work for v1 because my device is currently bricked. I does not create an SSID, I can't connect it via ethernet cable (192.168.1.1, 2.2, 1.2 all does not connect)
Interesting thing, when I connect the device to my laptop via ethernet cable, the ethernet icon constantly changes from the "ethernet connected without internet" icon to "there are wifi connections" icon - it does not stay the same, so I think device cannot initialize properly.

Is there **any way** I can recover it? Something like JTAG?

Thanks a lot